Formal definition of $f(x)$, being f:X→Y
Being $f:X \to Y$
which is the formal definition for $f(x)?$
(With a sintax in First Order Logic and Set Theory notation that could be use for algebraic manipulation.)

Maybe extension by definitions is what you're looking for.
